# Get current pos order on screen from api rpc (xml or json) in odoo pos

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-11, point-of-sale, pos

There is always only one pos order displayed at a time in the odoo pos.

How can I get this specific pos order using rpc api ?

Answer (score 2):

The way POS order in Odoo works that it only syncs orders with backend server after the order is confirmed that is after the payment is confirmed. Until then, the orders are stored in the browser localstorage. `rpc` is used to get data from Odoo backend from an external service, so it is possible to get Pos Orders that are confirmed from current open sessions using `rpc` via `pos.order` model but I don't think it is possible to get currently processing POS order. You can get the current POS Order object from browser console by running the following command `posmodel.get_order()`.

[image: POS Order]

Comment: can we get current order on screen Payment in js file odoo, i did tried many ways but it always return null